# Why is my computer connecting to Skynet? Is it a virus or other type of malware?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, windows-registry, tcpip, malware

I recently ran a "netstat" command on my Windows XP system,
and saw some connections to "Iron.Skynet". Well Iron is my Computers Name, but I've not come across the name "Skynet" on my system before.

Worried that I had a malware or virus infection, I did a search of the filesystem for "skynet" and didn't find anything, but then I did a search in the registry for "Skynet" and found the following:

in the branch named:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\
```

there's a value named "DhcpDomain" and its value is "Skynet"

Does anyone know what this is all about? Should I be worried? I've run various virus scanners and none of them found anything.

Comment: late to the conversation, just curious what AV software did you have prior to doing all the suggest items? Also do you surf the net with admin privs or not? If you follow all the suggestions below and still run/surf as administrator you'll infected again in no time flat!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skynet is a rootkit, not good. It is difficult to detect and remove.

1. Download and run Stubware
   http://www.thestubware.com/malware_removal/skynet/

After you have rebooted to remove the skynet driver with Stubware, download and run MBAM, do a full system scan, when it is done scanning, allow it to remove anything it finds.

2 . Download, install and Update MBAM twice, then scan.
http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

MBAM Does Not provide Active protection, it only scans when you run it.

Stubware does provide active protection if you wish, if you do not want it, remove stubware after it has removed skynet, use add/remove programs.

.

.

Comment: i tried running stubware. but it seems a bit confusing.
there are a few hundred checkboxes displayed after the scan finished.
how do i know which ones to tick before i click Fix?

Comment: Don't do anything yet

Comment: btw out of curiosity why do you need to install and run mbam twice

Comment: oops already have, i ticked the box for "rootkit" and clicked "fix" then rebooted, am now running mbam...

Comment: After the scan, There is a radio button "Display suspicious items only", tick it, these will be the items to remove.

Comment: I said to Update MBAM twice, use the Update tab. Sorry for the confusion, Install only once.

Comment: Be sure to run stubware and MBAM again after reboots, some rootkits can be persistent, reinstalling themselves after the reboot.

Comment: the strange thing is, even though there is a checkbox and item listed under the heading "rootkit" the program also says "Suspicious items : 0"

Comment: Suspicious is something that is not a Definite infection, only suspicious, I usually do not remove suspicious items unless I know what they are for sure.

Comment: shouldnt the fact that theres a rootkit on my computer, well according to the scan, mean that there is something suspicious going on? im slightly confused by that

Comment: Suspicious means it is not a Positive hit like the known rootkit it found. If I had developed the software I would not have it flag suspicious items, only known infections. Also, I just noticed there is an update tab on the stubware program, it downloads the latest definitions of malware and rootkits.

Comment: Mack, nice detective work using Nestat.

Comment: thanks, im not having much luck getting rid of it. will keep trying...

Comment: Read this page on how to deal with infected files coming back

http://www.thestubware.com/malware_removal/stubbornfile/

.

Comment: You could also try this rootkit remover.

http://sites.google.com/site/rootrepeal/

.

Comment: in the end a mixture of multiple runs of thestubware and superantimalware (running from the latest hirens bootcd) seemed to shift the rootkit. (fingers crossed) though im not 100% sure its gone. thestubware is no longer reporting any rootkits though which is good.

Comment: Did you try rootrepeal?

Do another netstat also.

Comment: i did try rootrepeal but didnt have much success with it, i will try it again. the skynet entry is still in the registry though.

Comment: oops slightly embarrasing, i had actually renamed my router "skynet", but had forgotten all about it. doh! so it wasnt the rootkit that made that entry to the registry after all. must have just been a coincidence, its a good job i had forgotten naming the router skynet, otherwise i probably wouldnt have further investigated the problem.

i guess with rootrepeal, the special sauce is in creating a log file, and posting it to a relevant forum, and getting help there, as it doesnt seem to have any automated fixing function. i will give it a try.

Comment: "renamed my router "skynet""

What a coincidence!

Another tool to remove rootkits is gmer, documentation is not great but is supposed to be one of the best.
http://www.gmer.net/

Comment: damn, tried checking the system out with super anti spyware again from the bootcd, and the rootkit is back again, talk about stubborn...

its called Rootkit.Unclassified/USBHubB

im starting to think reformatting the disk might be the only way to get rid of it...